# JQuery - Increasing number in seconds

Tags: jquery

I have a working function that increases a number and I use it in a custom data field.

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".servCon").children(".eaService").each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('data-wow-delay', '0.' + (i+1) + '0s');
    });
});
```

HTML Output

```
<div class="servCon">
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.1s"></div>
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.2s"></div> 
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.3s"></div> 
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.4s"></div> 
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.5s"></div> 
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.6s"></div> 
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.7s"></div> 
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.8s"></div> 
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.9s"></div> 
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.1s"></div> 
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.11s"></div> 
    <div class="eaService" data-wow-delay="0.12s"></div> 
</div>
```

My issue is after "0.9s" it goes back to "0.1s" and then "0.11s" but what id like it to do is after "0.9s" go to "1.0s" then "1.1s" etc all the way to "1.9s" to "2.0s" and so forth. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do it like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".servCon").children(".eaService").each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('data-wow-delay', parseFloat((i+1)/10).toFixed(1) + 's');
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/16136xeh/)

Concept behind the idea,

- `index + 1` = `10` (if index is `9`)
- So `index + 1 / 10` will be `1`
- `(1).toFixed(1)` will be `1.0`

Comment: Perfect!, sorry to be a pain but while I have your brain, can you do the same but in increments of 2 e.g. 0.2s. 0.4s, 0.6s etc

Comment: Strange, the first update you did worked, the update now just gives each div data-wow-duration="2s"

Comment: @webmonkey237 Have you checked the demo? Make sure you are not making any typos while using the code given here.

Comment: Yeah its strange, the first reply you did I added to my project, worked great, now if I use the example or the example in your demo the output I get on all divs is data-wow-duration="2s", ill keep trying.

Comment: @webmonkey237 Can you make a simple demo over here? So that it would be easy for us to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: No sorry it was my fault with my class naming, its working great, your still awesome.